# KeyWordQuery and Two or More Arguments

Tags: search, keywordquery

How do you correctly structure a Keyword query with two or more variables?

```
<Query>
    <Context>
        <QueryText type="STRING">Path:/sitename/libraryname AND CONTAINS(taco)</QueryText>
    </Context>
    ....
    ....
```

I'm trying to search a given library for a string of text.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work:

```
<Query>
<Context>
    <QueryText type="STRING">taco AND path:https://sharepoint/sites/sitename/libraryname</QueryText>
</Context>
```